# Is it possible to get all errors that include a Message substring via the Track:js API?

Tags: trackjs

We use TrackJs to log JavaScript errors on Stack Overflow Talent. I want to export a csv of all errors that include the substring `"%couldn't load id%"` within the Message field.

[The API documentation](http://docs.trackjs.com/data-api/index) doesn't make it clear that this is possible. Is this possible?

Comment: Hey Sam, Todd from TrackJS here. We saw this and we'll get you an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately we do not offer substring querying capability at this time :(  The main use case for the API is bulk export to store your JS error data in other third party systems (though we are certainly amenable to supporting other use cases ;))

To that end though, the API is meant to be quick, and be able to return lots of results per query.  It's no problem to retrieve up to 1000 records per page (using the `size` query parameter) and filter after the fact.